# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while finding the maximum difference between two consecutive elements in array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

I cannot find a logistic algorithm to find **the maximum difference between two consecutive indexes** in an array. When I used the method in my code, my client page gave me an error saying I have an *outofbounds Exception*. Any suggestions? If you need more code then just ask.

```
//method returning the largest change between two consecutive days
    public int NetChange()
    {
      int BiggestNet = temps[0] - temps[1];
      for( int i = 0; i < temps.length; i++ )
      {
         if( (temps[i] - temps[i+1]) > BiggestNet )
         {
            BiggestNet = (temps[i] - temps[i+1]);
         }
      }
      return BiggestNet;
     }
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at Forecast.NetChange(Forecast.java:105)
    at Forecast.toString(Forecast.java:120)
    at ForecastClient.main(ForecastClient.java:12
```

Comment: Once `i` equals `temps.length - 1` (the last iteration), you are trying to index `temps.length` since you are doing `i + 1`, causing your exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
for( int i = 0; i < temps.length; i++ )
```

To

```
for( int i = 0; i < temps.length - 1; i++ )
```

`temps.length` will give you the length of the array not using zero based counting, but it is accessed by zero based indicies. So if i = temps.length - 1, that is actually the last element in the array. If you then try to access temps[i+1] that will be longer than your array and thus out of bounds.

Answer (score 3):

Issue is with these two pieces of code...    `i < temps.length` and `temps[i+1]`

When i is equal to temps.length -1 which is last iteration of the loop, i+1 will be equal to temps.length. It means you are trying to access array[10] when the array has 10 elements. But array only contains 0 to 9 as index.

changing `i < temps.length` to `i < temps.length-1` will fix the issue..

Answer (score 1):

Since your loop variable `i` goes from `0` to `temps.length - 1` (because of `<`) and you have in the body

```
temps[i+1]
```

when `i` takes the value of `temps.length - 1` (the last value it can take), when you reach

```
temps[temps.length - 1 + 1]
```

is the same of

```
temps[temps.length]
```

it will raise an Excepction, since an array can only be accessed from `0` to `length - 1`.

**How to solve this?** You could try decreasing the last value of `i` in `1`. In other words:

```
for(int i = 0; i < temps.length - 1; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

temps[i+1] is the issue

when i is the last index, i+1 will give exception.